# Same where conditions but wrong result in mysql delete and select

Tags: mysql, select, procedure

```
DELETE
FROM TB_VALIDATE_PARAM
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(c_object_id, c_column_code)) NOT IN (
    SELECT UPPER(CONCAT(COL.TABLE_NAME, COL.COLUMN_NAME))
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS AS COL
    WHERE COL.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'jlink'
);

SELECT * 
FROM TB_VALIDATE_PARAM
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(c_object_id, c_column_code)) NOT IN (
    SELECT UPPER(CONCAT(COL.TABLE_NAME, COL.COLUMN_NAME))
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS AS COL
    WHERE COL.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'jlink'
);
```

As you see,the database is MYSQL.The same conditions in *DELETE* and *SELECT*.But when the *SELECT* one can't get any rows, the *DELETE* one delete all data in the table. I'm sure the table *TB_VALIDATE_PARAM* has so many rows.Is that Mysql analysis the conditions different in *SELECT* and *DELETE*?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that nothing is happening to your database in between your `SELECT *` and the `DELETE`?

Comment: It might be helpful to describe the table and give some rows as example.

Comment: Yes,I'm sure nothing is happening when I execute the SQL.I repeat it three times but got same result.difficult to understand why.@Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: The table TB_VALIDATE_PARAM just have two columns,one is **c_object_id** and the other is  **c_column_code**。The colomn **c_object_id** save the table name in my database and the **c_column_code** save the column name.@jaypi

Comment: Just to check; are you using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: No,I configed the my.cnf   lower_case_table_names=1 to make it case insensitive.@Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works for you.

```
DELETE FROM TB_VALIDATE_PARAM 
USING TB_VALIDATE_PARAM AS TP INNER JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS AS COL
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(TP.c_object_id, TP.c_column_code)) <> UPPER(CONCAT(COL.TABLE_NAME, COL.COLUMN_NAME))
AND COL.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'jlink'
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try it . But  I really  want to find out why my sql  script can work correctly.